# Childbrowser with phonegap on Android?

Tags: android, cordova

I can't get the childbrowser to work on Android.
I have followed the instructions on: https://github.com/brycecurtis/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser/

I have installed Eclipse and all the other stuff needed to compile an 
app and all works as it should. 
It is running in the emulator and I can also create an apk file.

So now I'm trying to get the childbrowser to work, like below.

1. I added the childbrowser.java file in my workspace/appname/ 
   src/com/phonegap/plugins/childBrowser/ folder.
2. And the childbrowser.js file in my workspace/appname/assets/www/ 
   folder.
3. I have linked to the phonegap.0.9.4.js and the childBrowser.js 
   files in my index file.
4. I added this in the manifest file

> ```
> >     <activity android:name="com.phonegap.DroidGap"
> > android:label="@string/app_name">
> >             <intent-filter>
> >             </intent-filter>
> >             </activity>
> ```

1. The link that should open the childbrowser looks like this:

> ```
>    <a href="#" onClick="window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage("thewebpage.html");">Open</a>
> ```

And it still isn't working? I'm just testing in the emulator as I don't have a android phone here right now, isn't the childbrowser working in the emulator? 
Or have I missed something else? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use phonegap.0.9.4.js as well and it is working for me. The childBrowser should work after PhoneGap JS throws event 'deviceready'. So I added the following code.

```
var url="http://www.google.com";

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage(url);       
}
```

Some tips, as I encountered some issues as well:

1. The javascript file I downloaded is childbrowser.js, all lowercase, not childBrowser.js
2. Make sure that ChildBrowser.java is compiled in the correct folder. Check eclipse bin folder
3. For an external web page use http:// in front.
4. The Javascript is a different for Android and iPhone. For example on Android you do not call ChildBrowser.install(); So example code is also different for iPhone/Android/BlackBerry

Answer (score 1):

Try using phonegap.0.9.5.js  and let knw if you have any problem.I followed the same link its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Check Eclipse's BuildPath.

Some Eclipse versions have a Build Path entry in the context-sensitive right-click on a file/folder, some you have to go to the root folder, right-click and select 'Properties', select 'Java Build Path', then select the 'Source' tab.

Verify your src folder includes 'All', and it and it's subfolders and the ClassBrowser.java file are not Excluded.

Also, create or open the res/xml/plugins.xml file and add this line in source mode:
`<plugin name="ChildBrowser" value="com.phonegap.plugins.childBrowser.ChildBrowser" />`

Also note Aschwin's tips.

Answer (score 1):

**Change:**

```
a href="#" onClick="window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage("thewebpage.html");"
```

**To:**

```
a href="#" onClick="window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage('thewebpage.html');"
```

The double quotes are likely what is keeping it from working. I see this is an old post, but maybe this will help someone else.