# PhoneGap 0.9.5 can not get latest Android ChildBrowser plugin to work

Tags: android, plugins, cordova

I followed steps from

https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser

I also checked everything listed on this post and still could not get it to work.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727052/childbrowser-with-phonegap-on-android
```

I am using the PhoneGap add-in to Eclipse Helios for IDE.

I tried below code

```
var url="http://www.google.com";

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    alert('device ready.');
    window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage(url);       
}
```

alert works fine, but childBrowser plugin won't show. The js code worked in childbrowser.js until below line:

```
PhoneGap.exec(this._onEvent, null, "ChildBrowser", "showWebPage", [url, options]);
```

And my debug statement in ChildBrowser.java is not being executed.

Can some guru shed some light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ChildBrowser has changed a lot lately and the instructions are likely wrong for PhoneGap 0.9.5. If you really need to stick with 0.9.5, you could get an older version of the ChildBrowser from github.

A better approach would be to use a more recent version of PhoneGap.  You can download the latest PhoneGap directly yourself or update to latest AppLaud Eclipse plug-in which is bundled with 1.0.0 (1.1.0 will come later this week). You can get it in Eclipse with *Help -> Install New Software https://svn.codespot.com/a/eclipselabs.org/mobile-web-development-with-phonegap/tags/r1.2/download*

Comment: Paul, you are right on and many thanks for speedy response. That is the last thing I had yet to  try the older version childbrowser plug-in. There seems to be a strong need for a mechanism or tool to manage or at least tablulate compatibility matrix of diff versions of plug-ins and PhoneGap.

Comment: Paul> So I have an app developed using MDS AppLaud 1.2, phoneGap0.9.5 using a few PhoneGap plugins. Now I need the latest childBrowser plugin. What do you recommend procedure to update PhoneGap1.0.0?  Do I must upgrade the AppLaud plugin first, or can I just download PhoneGap 1.0.0 files and replace existing files in my current 0.9.5 project?  Thanks,

Comment: It's probably easiest to create a new project (either with a newer AppLaud or by using its creation wizard to point at a newer PhoneGap download) If you don't do that, you can update your current project with the right files, but it's a little tricky. You should diff the entire directories and update files like AndroidManifest.xml, plugins.xml, phonegap.jar, phonegap.js, etc.

Comment: Paul> Thanks, again! I ended it up manually upgrade to PG1.1.0 and got it to work by trial and error. But I look forward to newer AppLaud plugin.

Comment: It just released. ;-) https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/jtEhbZSulTk